# Can I use onclick() event inside image tag?

Tags: image, events, onclick

I am trying to call the function by this way, but onclick() is not working  in the below code.

```
<img id="myImg" src="uploads/15051139151863de8020740a7899d26ead30d24770.jpg" onclick="modalview()" width="300" height="200">
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: I assume you are talking about JavaScript? There the `onClick` event also works with images. Could you share your code such that one doesn't have to guess what could have been gone wrong?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_cs‌​s_modal_img I am trying to open image in modal like this link example. And there are multiple images in my web page. and i want to apply this modal event on all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
<img src="http://example.com" onclick="function()">
```

Or you can use extern call like this:

```
$("img").click(function() {
  alert("Image clicked");
});
```

Comment: suppose I have multiple images, then same method will work or not.? Suggest me the answer if not?

Comment: This will work for **EVERY** image. If you want to select only one image use different selector, for example ID. 

HTML: `<img id="uniqueImage" ....` 
jQuery: `$("#uniqueImage").click(...`

Comment: but my images and there id are created dynamically. :(

Comment: I don't know what you are using but you could be able to choose different class/id for element in almost all frameworks/systems. If you need walkaround, you can use pseudo attributes. For example, if you want to fire alert only for **first** image you can use selector like `$('.parent-div').find('img:first').click(...`. I would need more information to help you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img  I am trying to open image in modal like this link example. And there are multiple images in my web page. and i want to apply this modal event on all images. Thanx in advance.

Comment: I've edited your w3 example - added jQuery and modified code - it works with all images now. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/9o78j4sv/